# How to sum and group for specific period of time

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have 30 min data and would like to sum hours and group by daytime from 02:00 AM of current date to 02:00 AM next date, how can I do that?:

```
create table test (code varchar2(50), hour number, daytime date); 

insert into test (code, hour, daytime) values ('K11','0.5','23-Feb-17')
insert into test (code, hour, daytime) values ('K11','0.5','23-02-17 00:30')
insert into test (code, hour, daytime) values ('K11','0.5','23-02-17 01:00')
insert into test (code, hour, daytime) values ('K11','0.5','23-02-17 01:30')
insert into test (code, hour, daytime) values ('K11','0.5','23-02-17 02:00')
insert into test (code, hour, daytime) values ('K11','0.5','23-02-17 02:30')
insert into test (code, hour, daytime) values ('K11','0.5','24-Feb-17')
insert into test (code, hour, daytime) values ('K11','0.5','24-02-17 00:30')
insert into test (code, hour, daytime) values ('K11','0.5','24-02-17 01:00')
insert into test (code, hour, daytime) values ('K11','0.5','24-02-17 01:30')
insert into test (code, hour, daytime) values ('K11','0.5','24-02-17 02:00')
insert into test (code, hour, daytime) values ('K11','0.5','24-02-17 02:30')
insert into test (code, hour, daytime) values ('K12','0.5','23-Feb-17')
insert into test (code, hour, daytime) values ('K12','0.5','23-02-17 00:30')
insert into test (code, hour, daytime) values ('K12','0.5','23-02-17 01:00')
insert into test (code, hour, daytime) values ('K12','0.5','23-02-17 01:30')
insert into test (code, hour, daytime) values ('K12','0.5','23-02-17 02:00')
insert into test (code, hour, daytime) values ('K12','0.5','23-02-17 02:30')
insert into test (code, hour, daytime) values ('K12','0.5','24-Feb-17')
insert into test (code, hour, daytime) values ('K12','0.5','24-02-17 00:30')
insert into test (code, hour, daytime) values ('K12','0.5','24-02-17 01:00')
insert into test (code, hour, daytime) values ('K12','0.5','24-02-17 01:30')
insert into test (code, hour, daytime) values ('K12','0.5','24-02-17 02:00')
insert into test (code, hour, daytime) values ('K12','0.5','24-02-17 02:30')
```

at end I'd like to get following data:

```
'K11',3,'23-02-17'
'K12',3,'23-02-17'
```

So it sum hours for example for K11 from ('K11','0.5','23-02-17 02:00') to ('K11','0.5','24-02-17 01:00')

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by subtracting two hours.  Here is one method:

```
select trunc(date - 2/24) as dte, sum(hours)
from t
group by trunc(date - 2/24)
order by dte;
```

Oracle now supports `interval` syntax, so you can also d:

```
select trunc(date - interval 2 hour) as dte, sum(hours)
from t
group by trunc(date - interval 2 hour)
order by dte;
```

Comment: no, that doesn't work, it add two hours, that's it but no grouping.

Comment: @JoeGreen . . . I don't understand your comment.  First, this *subtracts* two hours, it does not *add* them.  Second, the `group by` does the aggregation.